# bug "segmentation fault" in my c code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int firstState(char s[], int length);
int secondState(char s[], int length);
int thirdState(char s[], int length);
int forthState(char s[], int length);

int main()
{
    char string[10];

    gets(string);

    if( firstState(string, 0) )
        printf("Accept\n");
    else
        printf( "Not accept\n" );

    return 0;
}

int firstState(char s[], int length)
{  
    if(s[length] == 'a')
        return (secondState(s, length++));
    else if(s[length] == 'b')
        return firstState(s, length++);
    else
        return 0;
}

int secondState(char s[], int length)
{  
    if(s[length] == 'a')
        return secondState(s, length++);
    else if(s[length] == 'b')
        return thirdState(s, length++);
    else
        return 0;
}

int thirdState(char s[], int length)
{  
    if(s[length] == 'a')
        return secondState(s, length++);
    else if(s[length] == 'b')
        return forthState(s, length++);
    else
        return 0;
}

int forthState(char s[], int length)
{  
    if(s[length] == 'a')
        return secondState(s, length++);
    else if(s[length] == 'b')
        return firstState(s, length++);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

It gave me a segmentation fault or core dumped I'm confused!!!
can someone explain why It gave me this kind of bug????
and tell how to debug to make my code run very clearly!!

I'm really tired with this :(

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Did the error message contain the line number? Where did it point?

Comment: What is the string you're testing with?

Comment: Does your platform include a debugger?

Comment: You tend to increment the offset many times without checking it against the length of `string`, which is just 10!

Comment: You're overrunning the string array.  I can only produce a seg fault by entering 10 or more characters.  You need to make the string array longer and validate the input against its maximum length.

Comment: Note: all the xxxState() functions can only return 0. There is no way to get a return != 0, if they ever return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segmentation Fault is an access violation, i.e. when the program tries to access emmory it's not supposed to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault.

In your case it's caused by unsafe indexing into array, e.g.

```
int firstState(char s[], int length)
{
...
return firstState(s, length++);
...
}
```

You don't actually check if new length is still within bounds, so if the string wasn't null-terminated, which it probably isn't in your case, then you'll have an infinite loop resulting in SegFault.

For debugging, using a GUI would be the most sane approach, try Visual Studio on Windows, Eclipse on everything else.

Answer (score 7):

You have an infinite recursion,

```
return (secondState(s, length++));
```

The `length` argument passed is the value of `length` before the increment, so you only ever look at the first `char`.

Pass the `length` argument as `length + 1`, and check that `length` is smaller than 10 (the length of the `char` array `string`).

On another note,

```
gets(string);
```

is very unsafe, if the input is longer than nine characters, you write outside the allocated memory. Use

```
fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);
```

instead.

---

Well, since it takes only the abovementioned fixes and the change of one return value, the most part of the logic was correct, the fixed code:

```
// #include<string.h> <- We don't use that
#include<stdio.h>

// Match the grammar (a+b)*abb

int firstState(char s[], int length);    // nothing of the suffix matched
int secondState(char s[], int length);   // matched one character of the suffix
int thirdState(char s[], int length);    // matched two
int forthState(char s[], int length);    // matched the complete suffix

int main()
{
    char string[10];
    // Get a 0-terminated string into the buffer.
    fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);

    if( firstState(string, 0) )
        printf("Accept\n");
    else
        printf( "Not accept\n" );

    return 0;
}

int firstState(char s[], int length)
{  
    if(s[length] == 'a')  // first character of suffix matched
        return (secondState(s, length+1));
    else if(s[length] == 'b')  // nothing matched
        return firstState(s, length+1);
    else    // end of string in not-accepting state
        return 0;
}

int secondState(char s[], int length)
{  
    if(s[length] == 'a')  // the old matched 'a' wasn't part of the suffix, the new may be
        return secondState(s, length+1);
    else if(s[length] == 'b') // now matched two characters of the suffix
        return thirdState(s, length+1);
    else    // end of string in not-accepting state
        return 0;
}

int thirdState(char s[], int length)
{  
    if(s[length] == 'a')  // last three chars aba, the last 'a' could be part of the suffix
        return secondState(s, length+1);
    else if(s[length] == 'b')  // full suffix matched
        return forthState(s, length+1);
    else    // end of string in not-accepting state
        return 0;
}

int forthState(char s[], int length)
{  
    if(s[length] == 'a')  // another char, start a new candidate for the suffix
        return secondState(s, length+1);
    else if(s[length] == 'b')  // another char, can't be part of the suffix, start over
        return firstState(s, length+1);
    else        // end of string in accepting state, yay!
        return 1;
        // return s[length] == '\0';
        // if characters other than 'a' and 'b' need not signal the end of the string
}
```

Comment: line 26:  3059 Bus error               stdbuf --error=0 --output=0 "$@"

Comment: What exactly produced that error message? Doesn't look like any error message I ever got, what's the OS?

Comment: my code is to accept any string that match with this regular expression (a+b)*abb 
now when I put abb it prints Not accept and this is wrong it should print accept

Comment: The "any string" together with the Kleene star makes it somewhat hard because you don't know how long the string is going to be. So maybe a `char`-wise reading of the input is needed. Either way, have you an idea how to write a simple state machine? Instead of calling functions recursively, do it in a loop, changing a `state` variable?